# Does this translation of a sentence accurately capture the information and grammar of the original sentence?

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice

## Background

I am currently trying to translate this sentence, which comes out of an informational flyer.

“那就一定不要错过[北京留学生友会]即浖联会为新老同学们免费举办的[汽车知识讲座]”。

## Attempt

My attempt at a translation is this.

"Then you absolutely must not miss the chance to join the Undergraduate Chinese Student Organization's and the Beijing Students Studying Abroad Friendship Club's informational courses on cars, conducted free of charge for new and old students."

I think I have a good understanding of the beginning of the sentence, which asks readers to take advantage of this opportunity provided by the organization.

For the latter part, I can make out that there are free informational meetings about cars for new and old students alike, but I am not certain how the grammar works to connect it with the first part of the sentence.

Specifically, I do not know how '即浖' is being used, or if the two together even make a word. '浖' does not seem to be in common Chinese-English dictionaries. Turning to Chinese dictionaries suggested that it means something like 'boundary'.

Comment: I think your issue is that you have a typo. I'm fairly sure 即浖 is actually 即将. That word should be in all Chinese-English dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"北京留学生友会" -- Do you mean "北京留学生校友会"？ If that is the case, then this is how I would do it:

Then you absolutely must not miss the upcoming seminar on “Knowing your Motor Vehicles”, presented by the Beijing Foreign Students and Alumni Association. Admission is free for all (old and new) students.

Better still, omit the words in parentheses, since "all" already includes "old and new".

Answer (score 0):

My translation is "Undergraduate Chinese Student Organization's and the Beijing Students Studying Abroad Friendship Club's courses about car knowledge are coming. These courses are free to all freshmen and current students. Do not miss it."

即将 means will happen very soon. So you can use "is coming" or "is on the way".

old means 年龄上的“老”. It is better to say "current students".

"take advantage of" means 利用. It is not positive here. It is better to use "value" which means 珍惜.

Hopefully, it can help.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> Then do not miss the upcoming Vehicle Knowledge Lecture(Speech) held by the [Beijing
>   Abroad Student Friends Club], conducted free of charge for students
>   and new comers.